# Reading file from HDFS using Spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hdfs, spring-batch

I've to write a Spring batch which will read a file from HDFS and will update the data in MySQL DB.

The source file in HDFS contains some report data, in CSV format.

Can someone point me to an example of reading a file from HDFS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FlatFileItemReader` in Spring Batch works with any Spring Framework `Resource` implementation:

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<String> itemReader() {
    Resource resource; // get (or autowire) resource
    return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<String>()
            .resource(resource)
            // set other reader properties
            .build();
}
```

So if you manage to have a `Resource` handle pointing to a HDFS file, your are done.

Now in order to have a HDFS resource, you can:

- Use [Spring for Hadoop](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hadoop/docs/2.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/springandhadoop-fs.html#using-hdfs-resource-loader). Once the HDFS file system is configured, you would be able to get the resource from the application context with `applicationContext.getResource("hdfs:data.csv");`
- Implement your own `Resource` using Hadoop APIs (like shown in the answer by Michael Simons). I see that some folks already did this [here](https://github.com/swe-zzf/spring-hadoop/blob/master/spring-hadoop-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/hadoop/fs/HdfsResource.java)

Hope this helps.

Comment: BTW, the Spring for Hadoop project provides some extensions to Spring Batch that you might find useful. See here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hadoop/tree/master/spring-hadoop-batch/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/hadoop/batch

Comment: Nice. There had to be something from the Spring Portfolio. Cool, that it uses the `Resource`-API.