# read files from hdfs location using spring batch 4 java config

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I want read all the files from HDFS location and process files sequentially using spring batch.Currently I was using the MultiResourceItemReader to read the files from local file system and processing it.

Comment: This answer may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52774679/5019386

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading file from HDFS using Spring batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52770768/reading-file-from-hdfs-using-spring-batch)

Answer (score 0):

l have  Read the files from HDFS Location to local  file system and spring batch read the files from the local file system.

```
    //Read the files from the hdfs to local file system
        private Resource[] getMultipleResourceItemreader() {
                ArrayList<Resource> resource = new ArrayList<Resource>();
                org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration configuration= new   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration();
                configuration.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://localhost:9000");
                configuration.set("fs.hdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());
                System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME", "xxxx");
                System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "D:\\rajesh\\softwares\\winutils");
                FileSystem fs;
                try {
                    fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create("hdfs://localhost:9000"), configuration);
                    FileStatus[] files = fs.listStatus(new Path("hdfsfilelocation"));
                    for (int i=0;i<files.length;i++){
                        //resource.add( context.getResource(files[i].getPath().toString()));
                        fs.copyToLocalFile(files[i].getPath(), new Path(batchConfigurationProperties.getCsvFilePath()));
                        deleteTempFile(batchConfigurationProperties.getCsvFilePath(),".crc");

                    }


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
 File configJsonDirectory = new File(batchConfigurationProperties.getCsvFilePath());
        File[] csvFileList = configJsonDirectory.listFiles();
        for (File file : csvFileList) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                resource.add(new FileSystemResource(file.getPath()));
            }
        }
        return resource.toArray(new Resource[resource.size()]);
    }
```

Comment: how to read the file  and process from hdfs location using flatfileItemreader with out copying  into local file system from hdfs